# check numeric value in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, icefaces

```
<ice:inputText id="txt-tlmanage-quantity"
                value="#{createToolsOrderBean.toolsOrderVO.quantity}" tabindex="7"
                onkeydown="moveFocus(event, 'txt-tlmanage-unitprice')"
                style="margin-left: 4px;margin-bottom: 4px;">
            </ice:inputText>
```

this page is submitted when i press button by calling `createSomething` method. But this method can't call when i entered string value as `quantity` is of type Integer.It will gives error backside, But how one can know , What's going to be wrong ?.

I use `<ice:message>` , but it will give long error description on page.

```
Error Meaasage : 

mainForm:txt-tlmanage-quantity: 'dsad' must be a number between -2147483648 and 2147483647 Example: 9346
```

Is there any way to print my own error message ?

Comment: It's hard to understand your question. Would it be possible for you to make it clearer?

Comment: i don't quite get it... you want that the inputText only accept number then go with the converter, you want to display your own message the use http://www.javadabbadoo.org/apendice/jsf/mensajesEstandar/index.html but i dont understand what is it tha you need?

Answer (score 1):

You should add an integer converter to your ice:inputText. This will convert the entered string to integer.

```
<ice:inputText id="txt-tlmanage-quantity"
            value="#{createToolsOrderBean.toolsOrderVO.quantity}" tabindex="7"
            onkeydown="moveFocus(event, 'txt-tlmanage-unitprice')"
            style="margin-left: 4px;margin-bottom: 4px;">
    <f:converter converterId="javax.faces.Integer"/>
</ice:inputText>
```

You will still have an error message if you don't enter an integer. To display a custom message instead of the built-in you should create a message bundle. Create a properties file in one of your packages, and add your custom error message:

```
javax.faces.converter.IntegerConverter.INTEGER={2}: ''{0}'' must be a number consisting of one or more digits.
javax.faces.converter.IntegerConverter.INTEGER_detail={2}: ''{0}'' must be a number between -2147483648 and 2147483647 Example: {1}
```

Add this properties file as a resource bundle to the `faces-config.xml`:

```
<faces-config> 
     <application>
         <message-bundle>my.package.mypropertiesfile</message-bundle>
     </application> 
</faces-config>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, edit and paste the error, it will help us to help you.

If you want to show a custom error, use `FacesMessage`

Example:

```
public void testingErrorMessages() {

   try {
      throw new Exception("");
   } catch(Exception exc) {
      FacesMessage facesMsg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, null, "Error message here!");
      FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, facesMsg);
   }
}
```

Just add it and update the `<ice:message>`. `reRender` for RichFaces and `update` for PrimeFaces, but I don't know how it works in IceFaces..

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that he is not telling you that you may not use any letters?

You'll fix this, by using e.g. a converter.

Just add the following snippet to your inputText attributes:

```
converter="javax.faces.Integer"
```

When you gonna submit now, you will receive an error at your . If you want to create custom error messages use an validator. You'll find a good tutorial [here](http://www.javabeat.net/tips/71-write-your-own-validator-in-jsf.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use converter attribute in jsf for accepting only numeric values

If you want to print your own error message in jsf then you can use converterMessage attribute.

```
<h:inputText id="textCreditCardNumberId" label="CreditCard Number"
converter="javax.faces.Integer" converterMessage="Please enter numeric only" 
maxlength="16" styleClass="controlfont" 
value="#{OnlineReservationBean.creditCardNumber}"></h:inputText>
```